# Dynamic ellipsis support for Android autosizing TextViews

Tags: android, textview, android-support-library, ellipsis, autosize

The new [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html#setting-textview-autosize) are pretty awesome, but it seems a fundamental thing is missing: ellipses.

Adding ellipses still requires defining the `maxLines` attribute, but if I want to be able to dynamically resize the text size according to the text view boundaries, I'd also like to be able to dynamically add ellipses when needed. Right now, if the text doesn't fit even with the minimum text size, it just gets cropped.

How could I add support for dynamic ellipses without giving up the new autosizing support?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best solution I came up with so far was to programmatically set the `maxLines` to the proper value on runtime. Something like this will get the job done:

```
fun TextView.setMaxLinesForEllipsizing() = doOnPreDraw {
  val numberOfCompletelyVisibleLines = (measuredHeight - paddingTop - paddingBottom) / lineHeight
  maxLines = numberOfCompletelyVisibleLines
}
```

Be aware that this depends on Android KTX (but can also be easily achieved with a regular `OnPreDrawListener`).

Then we can simply call this extension from any `TextView` we want to get the dynamic ellipsis.

```
textView.setMaxLinesForEllipsizing()
```

If the text changes it might be necessary to call it again, though. So it might also possible to reach a more complete (and complicated) solution by moving this logic to a custom `TextView` and maybe overriding `onTextChanged()` there.