# Android - Put ellipsis if there's collision between Text Views

Tags: android

I would like to check if there's a collision between Text Views, if there is, ellipsis should be displayed instead of them colliding with each other.

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286469/dynamic-ellipsis-support-for-android-autosizing-textviews), but it doesn't work on mine (probably because of the font family that I'm currently using, too many spaces)

[image]

Here's some of the XML code, (I'm using Constraint layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            tools:context=".SettingsActivity">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/screenText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Screen"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/songsText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Songs"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitLine_hor3" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/fontSizeInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                android:divider="#8e8e8e"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fontSizeText"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fontSizeText" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/fontFamilyInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fontFamilyText"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fontSizeInput"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fontFamilyText" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/searchUsingInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/searchUsingText"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/darkModeInput"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/searchUsingText" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/displayOrderInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/displayOrderText"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/searchUsingInput"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/displayOrderText"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fontSizeText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="Font Size"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/screenText" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorGray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fontSizeText" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/splitLine_hor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorGray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fontFamilyText" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/splitLine_hor2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorGray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/copyTextText" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/splitLine_hor3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorGray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/darkModeText" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/splitLine_hor4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorGray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchUsingText" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/splitLine_hor5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorGray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/displayOrderText" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/splitLine_hor7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorGray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/swipeHymnText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fontFamilyText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="Font Family"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fontSizeText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SplitLine_hor1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/copyTextText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="Copy Texts"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fontFamilyText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitLine_hor" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/darkModeText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="Dark Mode"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/copyTextText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitLine_hor2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/searchUsingText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="Search Using"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/darkModeText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/songsText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/displayOrderText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="Display Order"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/searchUsingText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitLine_hor4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/swipeHymnText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="Swipe Through Songs"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/displayOrderText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitLine_hor5" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/copyTextInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/copyTextText"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fontFamilyInput" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/darkModeInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/darkModeText"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/copyTextInput" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/swipeHymnInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/swipeHymnText"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/displayOrderInput" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Kindly share full xml

Comment: Hi @IntelliJAmiya, shared. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting a horizontal linear layout inside your constraint layout. Place it where your 
fontFamilyInput spinner is currently located. Next, place your fontFamilyText TextView and your fontFamilyInput spinner (in that order) inside the linear layout.

You can now use weights inside the two child views to declare where on the screen the text view stops and the spinner begins.

However, remember that this is just one approach.

Comment: Additionally, you can place your other text view / spinner pair inside a seperate horizontal linear layout of their own. This can help to keep things evenly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your TextView `MaxEms` determins the number of character before ellipsis is shown

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxEms="15" 
android:singleLine="true"
```